# How to open a JQuery UI Combobox in the on click event?

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui

I'm trying to open a JQuery UI Combobox when I click on it, basically what I want is this:

```
$("#auto").bind("focus", function () {
    this.value = '';
    $(this).autocomplete("search", '');
});
​
```

[Auto Open](http://jsfiddle.net/gEuTV/)

But in a combobox.

The problem is that Im not able to get the focus or click event to be trigger.

I've try the click and bind focus events on: the actual field, the input field created by jquery but none of them since to work.

How could I get this to worked in the JQueryUI ComboBox?

**Update**

I've just noticed that I get the event trigger when I open the options and mouse over the options. But again what I want is to trigger it when I click on the input part.

**CODE **

Razor Code

```
<div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Lugar, "Nombre del Lugar")
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.DropDownList("Lugar", String.Empty)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Lugar)
        </div>
```

JavaScript Code

```
$("#Lugar").combobox();
```

Events

```
$("#Lugar").click(function () {
        alert("Handler for .click() called.");
    });


$("#Lugar-input").bind("focus", function ()
    {
        alert("a");
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add when creating the input field in the click event a call to the function openMethod

```
var input = this.input = $("<input>")
                    //.appendTo(wrapper)
                    .insertAfter( select )
                    .val(value)
                    .attr("title", "")
                    **.click(openmethod)**
```

**Function Openmethod**

```
var openmethod = function () {
                    // close if already visible
                    if (input.autocomplete("widget").is(":visible")) {
                        input.autocomplete("close");
                        return;
                    }

                    // work around a bug (likely same cause as #5265)
                    $(this).blur();

                    // pass empty string as value to search for, displaying all results
                    input.autocomplete("search", "");
                    input.focus();
                };
```